# how to get TIMESTAMP column from Oracle DB into C++ (MFC or WIN32)?

Tags: c++, oracle, timestamp

I need to get value of column (TIMESTAMP) from oracle DB into C++. Then which dataype i should map to access database field (In MFC or WinAPI any) or what should in do to do this in proper manner.

Thanks,
Anuj Seharavat

**edit**

Additional info:  I need to fetch data from database.  I am using CRecordset class and function RFX_Date is used there in DoFieldExchange(). RFX_Date has three forms (using CTime, TIMESTAMP_STRUCT and COleDateTime). Using Oracle at backend. I tried all three versions but not getting the values from database.

*NB: additional info extracted from OP comment to response.*

Comment: Please *edit your question* to give us more information instead of embedding it in comments down the thread.  SO is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the timestamp into a time type:

```
std::istringstream i( timestamp_string );
std::time_t t;
i >> t;
```

Take a look at the ctime header for a description on time_t if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for reply so quick...but i need to fetch data from database & i am using CRecordset class and function RFX_Date is used there in DoFieldExchange(). RFX_Date got three forms (using CTime, TIMESTAMP_STRUCT and COleDateTime). Using oracle at backend. I tried all three versions but not getting the values from database.